# Coloco un vídeo con HTML5, en local funciona pero en desarrollo, no. utilizo React y AWS amplify

Tags: html5, reactjs, aws

```
import video from '../../video/HomePage.mp4';
import '../Homepage/HomePage.css';
import React from 'react';
import Card from '../../components/Card/OutlinedCard'
import { Grid } from '@mui/material';
```

Este es el código de mi componente donde carga el vídeo:

El video está ubicado en la carpeta raíz del proyecto, sin embargo creo que no es un cuestión de ruta porque en local funciona correctamente.

Es un pagina estatica y no tienen backend.

```
const HomePage = () => {
    const justifyContent = {
        display: { xs:'none', md: 'flex' },
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems:"center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        textAlign:"center",
    };
    return (
        <>
            <div className="remoteVideo-container">
               <video   className="remoteVideo" loop autoPlay muted src={video}></video>
            </div>
            <Grid container spacing={2} columns={12} sx = {justifyContent}>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                     <Card/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </>
    )
}
export default HomePage
```

Comment: Y en la consola del navegador no tenes ningun mensaje? Si inspeccionas el HTML cual es la parte que no se arma correctamente?

Comment: Lo impresionante es que se arma todo eL HTML en ambas parte, pero parece no reconocer la ruta del vídeo. y digo parece porque no arroja un error en la consola.  y en local me funciona perfectamente. mientras que en el servidor no.

Answer (score 0):

En mi experiencia, si has creado tu aplicacion React con el create-react-app te recomiendo que coloques contenido estatico pesados en el public de tu proyecto, la ruta sera /videos/<NOMBRE_VIDEO> , y cambia el tag html por source con el atributo src igual a /videos/NOMBRE_VIDEO com el ejemplo a continuación:

```html
<source src="videos/<NOMBRE_VIDEO>" type="video/mp4"/>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).